# Chose the wrong project for deployment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I have deployed my openapi configuration to the wrong cloud platform project. Now it shows the metrics in the wrong project.

Delete the config is not a option because the soft delete is holding the service for 30 Days.

Is there a solution to move the Endpoints Metrics from one to a other project?

Comment: In your OpenAPI spec, is your "host" of the form "<PROJECT_ID>.appspot.com" or "<API>.endpoints.<PROJECT_ID>.cloud.goog"? Or is it a custom name?

Comment: It is a custom domain.

Comment: A custom domain is trickier. Please post your question on the Cloud Endpoints Google Group and we can assist you further. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-endpoints

Comment: I have posted the question to the group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-endpoints/kp_TmJmPOhg